# Cannot convert java.util.Optional<class> with stream

Tags: java-8

I'm trying to use stream in java, i had a student class:

```
@Entity
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class Student {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
```

I added some students:

```
Stream.of("John","Sophie","emilia").forEach(s->{
            studentRepository.save(new Student(s));
        });
```

The probleme is in the below code:

```
int[] empIds = { 1, 2, 3 };
        List<Student> students= Stream.of(empIds)
                .map(studentRepository::findById).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

i got this error: bad return type in method reference:cannot convert java.util.Optional to R. My IDE underline studentRepository::findById.
Many thanks.

Comment: `Arrays.stream(empIds)
      .mapToObj(id->studentRepository.findById(id).orElse(null))
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The First problem is `Stream.of` will create an stream of `int arrays` instead of stream of Integer

**For Example**

```
Stream.of(empIds).forEach(System.out::println);      //[I@7c3e4b1a
IntStream.of(empIds).forEach(System.out::println);   //1 2 3
```

So use `IntStream.of` or `Arrays.stream()`

If `findById()` is returning `Optional<Student>` then use `isPresent` to process only the `Optional` objects that contain `Student`

**Arrays.stream**

```
List<Student> students= Arrays.stream(empIds)
            .mapToObj(studentRepository::findById)
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**IntStream.of**

```
List<Student> students= IntStream.of(empIds)
            .mapToObj(studentRepository::findById)
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In current approach your are returning `List<Optional<Student>>`

```
List<Optional<Student>> students= IntStream.of(empIds)
            .map(studentRepository::findById).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: for first approach not to need `.filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)`

Comment: what id `Student` object in not present in `Optional`? it leads to `NoSuchElementException` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get-- @HadiJ

Comment: Even .filter(Optional::isPresent)  .map(Optional::get) are underlying and gave me another error

Comment: Try my updated answer, the problem is stream.of is creating an int array stream instead of integer stream @Gary

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use it in `map()` function, `StudentRepository.findById()` needs to return `Optional<Student>` instead of just `Student`.

Comment: can you update the question and include the code for StudentRepository.findById() as well?

Comment: even this code return the same error List<Optional<Student>> students= Stream.of(empIds)
                .map(studentRepository::findById).
                        collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: What i am trying to say is - return type of `findById` should be `Optional<Student>` instead of `Student`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, your answers helped me to derive a solution:

```
List<Student> students= Arrays.stream(empIds)
                .mapToObj(id->
                   studentRepository.findById(id).get())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And the response of deadpool is great also, we have to add .map(Optional::get) to get the stream of student because studentRepository::findById return stream of optioanl that's why the error.

```
List<Student> students= Arrays.stream(empIds)
                .mapToObj(studentRepository::findById)
               // .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `.mapToObj(id->
                   studentRepository.findById(id).get())` isn't correct since if `findById()`'s result will be empty so this code will throws _java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present_  also for second approach too.

Comment: Try test it with empty result. I mean suppose `findById()` method return empty result.